# A macro to set a particular transition between powerpoint slides before go to the next slide

Tags: vba, animation, powerpoint, slideshow

I'm working on a Slideshow where all the slides have set the "Push from Left" transition. I'm going to insert in every slide a button to go back to the previous one, and just when the button is pressed I'd like to switch the transition to "Push from Right", go to the previous slide, then set the transition to "Push from Left" again.
I wrote this, but it does not work:

```
Sub previousslide()
With ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View
    .Slide.SlideShowTransition.EntryEffect = ppEffectPushRight
    .GotoSlide (ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex - 1)
    .Slide.SlideShowTransition.EntryEffect = ppEffectPushLeft
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an ‘End With’ to complete the With-End With block. Also, I would skip referencing ActivePresentation object because it will work only if there is an active presentation. If you run the code above while running a .PPSX/.PPSM file then the code will fail. The code below removes the reference.

```
Sub PreviousSlide()
With SlideShowWindows(1).View
    .Slide.SlideShowTransition.EntryEffect = ppEffectPushRight
    .GotoSlide (SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.SlideIndex - 1)
    .Slide.SlideShowTransition.EntryEffect = ppEffectPushLeft
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint, the code runs althought it beaves a bit oddly. The first EntryEffect sets the "PushRight" transition, but the "preview" is on screen, so I see: Slide B <- Slide B. Then the slide changes with the new transition, so I see: Slide A <- Slide B. In the last instruction I get the preview of the new transition "PushLeft", so I see: Slide A -> Slide A.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to reference a slide:

Presentations.Item(#).Slides(#).SlideShowTransition.EntryEffect

This works whether or not a slideshow's running, the octothorps should be replaced by your intended 1-based index number

Also I've experienced that the code API applies different transition styles than the GUI

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the same thing. If you're on slide x and going to the previous slide, what you need to do is set the slide transition of slide x-1 to 'Push from Right'. If you're going to the next slide, you need to set the transition of slide x+1 to 'Push from Left'.

```
Sub previousSlide()
' Define previous slide index
Dim previousSlide As Integer
previousSlide = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex - 1
' Change slide transition of previous slide
ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(previousSlide).SlideShowTransition.EntryEffect = ppEffectPushRight
' Previous slide
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide (previousSlide)
End Sub
```

Strangely, I've noticed if slides start with NO animation, setting the animation using this code doesn't work. The animation must be pre-set manually to the Slide animation, then this code works. Strange...